# Google Adwords API PHP Client Add Keywords to Ad Group in Bulk

Tags: php, google-ads-api

To add an array of `$keywords` to my ad group I am currently using the following code:

```
$adGroupCriterionService = $adwordsUser->GetService('AdGroupCriterionService', 'v201109');

$operations = array();

foreach ($keywords AS $keyword) {
    $keywordobj = new Keyword();
    $keywordobj->text = $keyword;
    $keywordobj->matchType = 'BROAD';

    $keywordAdGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
    $keywordAdGroupCriterion->adGroupId = $identifier;
    $keywordAdGroupCriterion->criterion = $keywordobj;

    $keywordAdGroupCriterionOperation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
    $keywordAdGroupCriterionOperation->operand = $keywordAdGroupCriterion;
    $keywordAdGroupCriterionOperation->operator = 'ADD';

    $operations[] = $keywordAdGroupCriterionOperation;
}

$result = $adGroupCriterionService->mutate($operations);
```

This works fine. However, I've started to realise that doing such operations uses up API Units rather more quickly than I had anticipated. Is there a more API Unit friendly approach to doing this operation? Or is this simply the 'catch' with the Google Adwords API pricing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many keywords you're uploading at a time, you can use the [MutateJobService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/MutateJobService.html); the coding is a little more complicated but you should save 50% of the unit cost.

Comment: Excellent! And it's not actually too complicated to use at all. Found some videos which others with the same query might find interesting on the subject which includes sample code - http://www.talkminer.com/viewtalk.jsp?videoid=CV_kOTW3ldQ&q=

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs a quick code example, http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201109/CampaignManagement/AddKeywordsInBulk.php shows how to use MutateJobService, it is much more simpler than the old BulkMutateJobService. Also, the original video from API workshop days is here, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CV_kOTW3ldQ, presentations here: https://sites.google.com/site/awapiworkshops/slides-and-links. Same links as JoeR posted, but linked to the original site this time.

For any AdWords API related questions, the official forum (http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api) is the best place to ask questions. The group is very active, and Googlers from the API team regularly answer questions here.

Cheers,
Anash